# localStorage breaks when timer reaches double digits

Tags: javascript

I have a timer (in seconds) function, and it stores the recent time, and the best time, however if the recent time goes to double digits, the best time will simply be the last single digit timer score, any reason as to why it won't store double digit values?

```
    timer = () => {
        let time = document.getElementById("seconds");
        let bestTime = document.getElementById("bestTime");
        time.innerText++;

        localStorage.setItem("latestTime", time.innerText);
        localStorage.setItem("bestTime", bestTime.innerText);

        if (localStorage.getItem("bestTime") < time.innerText) {
            localStorage.setItem("bestTime", localStorage.getItem("latestTime"));
            bestTime.innerText = time.innerText;
        }
    };
```

[Key Value pairs in browser for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl6DP.png)

[The timer is 12s so the Highscore should be 12, but stops at 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlFaf.png)

Comment: Note you are comparing numerical strings in your if condition. This can lead to issues as the comparison happens lexically not numerically, ie `"10"<"2" === true`

Comment: just put `+` in front of your .innerText calls to coerce to number

Answer (score 0):

You are doing string comparisons rather than number comparisons.

Local storage and `element.innerText` both return strings rather than numbers, and string comparisons are done lexically. In string comparisons, `'1'<'9'`, but `'12'<'9'` because `'12'` starts with a 1.

```js
console.log('"12"<"9"','12'<'9')
console.log('12<9',12<9)
```

You need to convert your strings to numbers and then things should work fine:

an easy way to convert a string to a number is by putting a `+` in front of it: `+time.innerText`

```
    timer = () => {
        let time = document.getElementById("seconds");
        let bestTime = document.getElementById("bestTime");
        time.innerText++;

        localStorage.setItem("latestTime", time.innerText);
        localStorage.setItem("bestTime", bestTime.innerText);

        if (+localStorage.getItem("bestTime") < +time.innerText) {
            localStorage.setItem("bestTime", localStorage.getItem("latestTime"));
            bestTime.innerText = time.innerText;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Local Storage can only store strings, not numbers or anything else.

When you store a number into the Local Storage,  it will be automatically converted to a string, which isn't a problem.

However, your code doesn't convert it back after you retrieve it!

This:

```
localStorage.getItem("bestTime") < time.innerText
```

will receive two strings, and therefore use string comparison, in which `10` comes before `2` (as the first character is the most significant).

You'll have to convert them numbers, like:

```
+localStorage.getItem("bestTime") < +time.innerText
```